# What is the first $w$ such that a rectangle, $R_{w\times w-1}$ is minimally-square-partitioned by less than $w$ squares.

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, packing-problem, extremal-combinatorics, tiling

<sup><sup>**Motivated by:**

[Tiling an orthogonal polygon with squares](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16661/2755),

[How to prove that the minimum square partition of a 3X2 rectangle has 3 squares](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16809/2755),

[Minimum square partitions for 4x3 and 5x4 rectangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/560870/39567),

[What is the minimum square partition of an almost-square rectangle?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16826/2755).</sup></sup>

Let:

- An *almost-square-rectangle* be a rectangle that has a width  $w$ and height $h=w-1$.
- A *square partitioning* be a covering by non-overlapping squares; the entire rectangle must be covered, all the squares must be disjoint.
- A *minimum-square-partitioning* be a *square partitioning*, for which is no square partitioning that is made of a lesser number of squares.

The $R_{w\times w-1}$ rectangles illustrated below are minimally-square-partitioned by $w$ squares. Proofs here: [How to prove that the minimum square partition of a 3X2 rectangle has 3 squares](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16809/2755) and [Minimum square partitions for 4x3 and 5x4 rectangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/560870/39567)).

[image]

However, in general, a $R_{w\times w-1}$ rectangle can be partitioned into $\mathcal O(\log w)$ squares (see [What is the minimum square partition of an almost-square rectangle?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/16832/2755), and [Minimum tiling of a rectangle by squares](https://mathoverflow.net/q/44524/26677), which refer to a paper called [Tiling a Rectangle with the Fewest Squares](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316596901041) by Richard Kenyon.

My question:

> What is the minimum $w$, such that a $w\times w-1$ rectangle, $R_{w\times w-1}$, can be minimally-square-partitioned into $f(w)$ squares, and $f(w)<w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the proofs cited above, $w\geq 6$, and by Yuval's answer cited above, $w\leq 7$. So the only question is now whether a $6 \times 5$ rectangle can be covered with 5 squares. I think the answer is yes: it can be covered by three $2 \times 2$ squares and two $3 \times 3$ squares. So $w=6$.